# Converting DataView to DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, dataview

I have a form with **Search User Button** when I select the button the modal popup extender will show and user can search all the employees, when select value, the value selected should pass to the parent form with another gridview.

Now, I have a code which convert dataview to datatable. When debugging the value of index (s) is not passing to (idx).

```
Dim RowIndex As Integer = gvUser.EditIndex
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = TryCast(Session("dbCache_User"), DataView).Table.Clone

    Dim dv As New DataView(dt, "", "USR_IDNTY", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
    Dim s As String = TryCast(gvUser.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("lblUSR_IDNTY"), Label).Text
    Dim idx As Integer = dv.Find(s)

    dv(idx)("USR_ID") = row.Cells(1).Text
    dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text

    gvUser.DataSource = dv
    gvUser.DataBind()
```

When I'm trying to debug. I try to search one row with index 4; the value of (s)  is 4 but when passing to (idx) it is -1.

I need to find the value s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may not have read the relevant documentation.  This is from the documentation for the `DataTable.Clone` method:

> Clone creates a new DataTable with the same structure as the original DataTable, but does not copy any data (the new DataTable will not contain any DataRows). To copy both the structure and data into a new DataTable, use Copy.

If `dv` is a view of `dt` and `dt` contains no rows then of course `Find` returns -1.  Even without reading that documentation, why did you not pickup that your `DataTable` was empty?  That's one of the first things you should have checked.

Comment: -1 means no match. Anything else means that a match was found at that index. If `Find` returns 0 then that means a match was found in the first row. If you think it should be a different row then you're wrong. Either your expectations are wrong or you're doing something wrong. We can't help with that because we don't have your data.

Comment: So now I got match and passing data but got error "data exception was unhandled"                                                                                            
    dv(idx)("NAME") = row.Cells(2).Text

Comment: That's nothing to do with the topic of this question.  The question you asked has been answered so you should accept that answer and move on.  If you have another question, you should post that in a new thread, providing all the information relevant to that question only.